# How to properly combine multiple Drivers with RxSwift?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm combining a `viewDidAppear` and `filter` Drivers with RxSwift. And they work great. But when I introduce a third Driver, it stops calling `flatMapLatest` on the latest combine.

In my View Controller, I have these Drivers:

```
let filter: Driver<String>
let viewDidAppear: Driver<Void>
let refresh: Driver<Void>
```

And in my view model:

```
// On viewDidAppear, I download a list of portfolios

let viewDidAppearPortfolios = viewDidAppear
    .flatMapLatest({ (_) -> Driver<Result<[PortfolioModel]>> in        
        return networkService.request(Router.portfolios)!
            .responseCollections()
            .trackActivity(fetching)
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: .failure(NSError()))

    })
    .flatMapLatest({ (result: Result<[PortfolioModel]>) -> Driver<[PortfolioModel]> in

        switch result {
        case .success(let value): return Driver.just(value)
        case .failure(_): return Driver.just([])
        }

    })

// Then I combine with a filter from my search bar.

self.portfolios = Driver.combineLatest(viewDidAppearPortfolios, filter)
    .flatMapLatest { (portfolios: [PortfolioModel], filter: String) -> Driver<[PortfolioModel]> in

        if filter.isEmpty {
            return Driver.just(portfolios)
        }

        return Driver.just(portfolios.filter({ (portfolio) -> Bool in
            portfolio.portfolio.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(filter)
        }))

    }
```

**The above works!**

The network **requests a list** of portfolios, and **I'm able to filter** those results as I type, client side.

However, I'd like for the user to **pull to refresh**, and trigger the network **request again**! And so, I combine with my refresh driver.

And this:

```
Driver.combineLatest(viewDidAppearPortfolios, filter)
```

Becomes this:

```
Driver.combineLatest(viewDidAppearPortfolios, filter, refresh)
```

**Problem!**

After combining with `refresh` the `flatMapLatest` is **no longer called on viewDidAppear**! Only if I manually pullToRefresh.

```
Driver.combineLatest(viewDidAppearPortfolios, filter, refresh).flatMapLatest { _,_,_ in 
    // No longer get's called on viewDidAppear after combining with refresh
}
```

1. The `viewDidAppearPortfolios` still executes, so the network request
   is getting called!
2. Only if I manually pull to refresh do I get the
   list of portfolios that I previously requested...

Any idea why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like your `refresh` didn't emit a single event yet and so the `combineLatest` is not computed.
I tried this code to test:

```
let one = Driver.just(1)
let two = Driver.just(2)
let three: Driver<Int> = .just(3)

let result = Driver.combineLatest(one, two, three)
    .flatMapLatest {
        return Driver.just($0 + $1 + $2)
    }

result.drive(onNext: {
    print($0)
})
```

This prints 6 but if you use `let three: Driver<Int> = .empty()` this is not printing anything. So I guess you need a way to set an initial value to `refresh` stream.

Comment: That was it, thank you. In my case I added the `startWith` to my refreshControl: `refreshControl.rx.controlEvent(.valueChanged).startWith(()).asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())`

Comment: Driver.combineLatest is omg to me. I've been using Observables.merge for those drivers with covered in .asObservable().